# Efficient way to split and map float function on a string of points

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

How to use map/any other advance function to generate array of points?
I am using below code, which works well, but not readable or it is very basic version.

Is there any way I can use some *advanced* trick to generate same output? I am reading `map()` function, which we can use something like `list(map(int, [3.3,4.3,5.3]))`.

```
t = "517.30,363.60;511.27,385.41;508.63,406.12;505.62,424.20;502.23,444.91;500.35,468.26"
# line below, but is not readable, not sure about performance
points = [[float(x.split(',')[0]),float(x.split(',')[1])] for x in t.split(';')]
print(points)
```

Output:

```
[[517.3, 363.6], [511.27, 385.41], [508.63, 406.12], [505.62, 424.2], [502.23, 444.91], [500.35, 468.26]]
```

Comment: ``[list(map(float, x.split(","))) for x in t.split(";")]``

Comment: Do the pairs really need to be lists, or would tuples be ok as well?

Comment: tuples works too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `map` to shorten it and splitting it into two lines for readability:

```
>>> [[*map(float, x.split(','))]
     for x in t.split(';')]
[[517.3, 363.6], [511.27, 385.41], [508.63, 406.12], [505.62, 424.2], [502.23, 444.91], [500.35, 468.26]]
```

Or if tuples are ok (seems they likely might be):

```
>>> [*map(ast.literal_eval, t.split(';'))]
[(517.3, 363.6), (511.27, 385.41), (508.63, 406.12), (505.62, 424.2), (502.23, 444.91), (500.35, 468.26)]
```

Comparing my first one with Eugene's (three rounds, results are fairly stable, they're times so lower=faster):

```
0.905 Eugene Pakhomov
0.869 superb rain

0.905 Eugene Pakhomov
0.864 superb rain

0.909 Eugene Pakhomov
0.867 superb rain
```

Code:

```
from timeit import repeat

funcs = {
    'Eugene Pakhomov': lambda: [[float(i) for i in x.split(',')]
                                for x in t.split(';')],
    'superb rain':     lambda: [[*map(float, x.split(','))]
                                for x in t.split(';')],
}

t = "517.30,363.60;511.27,385.41;508.63,406.12;505.62,424.20;502.23,444.91;500.35,468.26"

for _ in range(3):
    for author, func in funcs.items():
        time = min(repeat(func, number=100000, repeat=20))
        print('%.3f' % time, author)
    print()
```

Comment: Interesting solution, I am using your solution since the `t` contains more than 200 points. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's very rare that you actually need `map` in Python. In general, you're better off using list/dict comprehensions:

```py
points = [[float(i) for i in x.split(',')]
          for x in t.split(';')]
```

Comment: Nice, do you think this is most efficient way of doing it ? I definitely not able to think anything else to do it more fast.

Comment: I have to disagree. map/filter can be exceptionally useful, especially if you only need to do one operation. Just because GVR has a thing against those functions doesn't mean we all have to.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo How do you know he has a thing against those?

Comment: @superbrain https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196

Comment: @snakecharmerb I know that. But that was over 15 years ago. Silvio spoke of the present.

Comment: In fact, map would be slower than list-comprehension by test.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Can you please share the test?

Comment: @superbrain By test, when handle some small datas, list comprehension is a little faster than map.But map is a little faster than list comprehension when the list is too long,

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Your fact disagrees with my test (see my answer). How come?